# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^n \csc(x) dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Just from messing around on WolframAlpha, I've come across an interesting integral. For the integral
$$
\operatorname{I}\left(n\right) =
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x^{n}\csc\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x\,,
$$
there are some pretty interesting answers when evaluating them at certain values. For example:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{I}\left(1\right) & = 2C
\\[2mm]
\operatorname{I}\left(2\right) & =
2\pi C - {7 \over 2}\,\zeta\left(3\right)
\\[2mm]
\operatorname{I}\left(3\right) & =
\frac{1}{128}\left[192\,\pi^{2}\,C -\psi^{\left(3\right)}
\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) +\psi^{\left(3\right)}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right]
\\[2mm]
\operatorname{I}\left(4\right) & =
\pi^{3}\,C -
24\pi\,{\rm i}\operatorname{Li}_{4}\left(-{\rm i}\right) + \frac{93}{2}\,\zeta(5) - \frac{7}{480}\,{\rm i}\pi^{5}
\end{align}

- With each step up, we introduce a new family of functions.
- I cannot for the life of me distinguish a pattern to try to come up with what $\operatorname{I}\left(n\right)$ might be.
- The only thing that I can discern, is obviously
  $\operatorname{I}\left(n\right)$ includes a term including $\pi^{n-1}\, C$.

Can someone give me some kind of idea as to how I might evaluate these $?$.

Comment: Heard. Can go ahead and delete it now, thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We find an explicit closed form for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Using $\sin(x)=\dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ and the geometric series (in the distributional sense, e.g. see the last remark of this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/302340/323432)) we obtain
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} x^n \csc(x)~dx=2i \int_0^{\pi/2} x^n \frac{e^{-ix}}{1-e^{-2ix}}~dx=2i\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} x^n e^{-(2k+1)ix}~dx. \tag{1}$$
We have the indefinite integral (eq. 2.321 in [Gradshteyn and Ryzhik 7th ed.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123736374)) for any $a\in \mathbb{C}$
$$\int x^n e^{ax}~dx=e^{ax}\left(\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{(-1)^j j! \binom{n}{j}}{a^{j+1}}x^{n-j}\right)+C,$$
which results in the definite integral
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} x^n e^{ax}~dx=e^{a\pi/2} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^j j! \binom{n}{j}}{a^{j+1}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n-j}\right)-\frac{(-1)^n n!}{a^{n+1}}.$$
Hence for $a=-(2k+1)i$ we have
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} x^n e^{-(2k+1)ix}~dx=i\cdot (-1)^k \left(\sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{j! \binom{n}{j}}{i^{j+1} (2k+1)^{j+1}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n-j}\right)+\frac{n!}{i^{n+1} (2k+1)^{n+1}}.$$
With this result, one can express $(1)$ in terms of [Dirichlet beta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function)
$$\beta(s):=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^s},$$
and [Dirichlet lambda functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletLambdaFunction.html)
$$\lambda(s):=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k+1)^s}=(1-2^{-s})\zeta(s),$$
where the final equality is valid for all $\Re(s)>1$.

---

Thus, the integral is given by the following if $n$ is even (we use that $i^l=i^{-l}$ if $l$ is even):
$$\scriptsize \begin{align*}\int_0^{\pi/2} x^n \csc(x)~dx&=2 i^n\cdot n!\lambda(n+1)-2 \sum\limits_{\substack{0\leq j\leq n \\ j~\mathrm{odd}}} \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n-j} i^{j+1} j! \binom{n}{j}\beta(j+1)\\&=\frac{(-1)^{n/2}\cdot n! (2^{n+1}-1)}{2^n}\zeta(n+1)-2 \sum\limits_{\substack{0\leq j\leq n \\ j~\mathrm{odd}}} \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n-j} i^{j+1} j! \binom{n}{j}\beta(j+1)\\&=\frac{(-1)^{n/2} \cdot n! (2^{n+1}-1)}{2^n}\zeta(n+1)+2\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor} \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n+1-2m} (-1)^{m-1} (2m-1)! \binom{n}{2m-1}\beta(2m). \end{align*}$$
Otherwise, if $n$ is odd
$$\begin{align*}\int_0^{\pi/2} x^n \csc(x)~dx&=-2 \sum\limits_{\substack{0\leq j\leq n \\ j~\mathrm{odd}}} \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n-j} i^{j+1} j! \binom{n}{j}\beta(j+1)\\&=2\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor} \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n+1-2m} (-1)^{m-1} (2m-1)! \binom{n}{2m-1}\beta(2m). \end{align*}$$
This agrees with @metamorphy's results (and yours). Note that we only sum over odd $j$ since the summands for even $j$ only contribute to the imaginary part of the integral, which we know is $0$ since the integrand is real on the domain of integration.

Answer (score 10):

Reexpress the integral as

\begin{align}
I(n)=&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^n \csc x\>dx
\overset{t=e^{i x}}=-\frac2{i^n}\int_1^i \frac{\ln^n t}{1-t^2}dt\\
=&\frac2{i^n}\left( \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^n t}{1-t^2}dt -\int_0^1  \frac{i\ln^n (it)}{1+t^2}dt \right)\\
=&\frac2{i^{n}}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^n t}{1-t^2}dt -\frac2{i^{n-1}} \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} (\frac{i\pi}2)^{n-k}\int_0^1  \frac{\ln^k t}{1+t^2}dt \tag1
\end{align}
and note that
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^n t}{1-t^2}dt=(1-2^{-n-1})n!\zeta(n+1)\\
&\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^k t}{1+t^2}dt=(-1)^k k! \beta(k+1)
\end{align}

Substitute above into (1) and keep only the real parts (i.e. odd $k$)
\begin{align}
 I(n) =\>(2-2^{-n})n!\zeta(n+1)\text{Re}(i^n)
- \sum_{k=1}^{[\frac{n+1}2]} (\frac{\pi}2)^{n+1-2k}\>\frac{2(-1)^k n!}{(n+1-2k)!} \>\beta(2k)
\end{align}

Comment: $+1$. Nice. That's the approach I had in mine.

Comment: This should be the highest-voted one ;)

Answer (score 9):

$I(n)$ expresses naturally using [Dirichlet's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function) $\beta$, in addition to Riemann's $\zeta$. Consider $$f(r,x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k\sin(2k+1)x=\frac{(1+r)\sin x}{1-2r\cos2x+r^2}\qquad(|r|<1)$$ so that $\int_0^{\pi/2}x^n f(r,x)\,dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k I_{n,k}$ with $I_{n,k}=\int_0^{\pi/2}x^n\sin(2k+1)x\,dx$. Now $$I_{0,k}=\frac1{2k+1},\qquad I_{n+1,k}=\frac{n+1}{(2k+1)^2}\Big((-1)^k(\pi/2)^n-nI_{n-1,k}\Big)$$ (the recurrence holds for $n\geqslant 0$, and is obtained using integration by parts).

It remains to do $r\to1^-$, when $2f(r,x)\to\csc x$ (and this is a [dominated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) convergence; another tool we need here is [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem)), concluding with $I(n)=2\sum_{k=0}^\infty I_{n,k}$, and use the recurrence given above. With [$\lambda(s)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_function)${}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(2n+1)^{-s}=(1-2^{-s})\zeta(s)$, the first few values of $I(n)$ are:

\begin{align*}
I(1)&=2\beta(2)
\\I(2)&=2\pi\beta(2)-4\lambda(3)&&\color{gray}{\ldots\frac72\zeta(3)}
\\I(3)&=\frac32\pi^2\beta(2)-12\beta(4)
\\I(4)&=\pi^3\beta(2)-24\pi\beta(4)+48\lambda(5)&&\color{gray}{\ldots\frac{93}{2}\zeta(5)}
\\I(5)&=\frac58\pi^4\beta(2)-30\pi^2\beta(4)+240\beta(6)
\\I(6)&=\frac38\pi^5\beta(2)-30\pi^3\beta(4)+720\pi\beta(6)-1440\lambda(7)&&\color{gray}{\ldots\frac{5715}{4}\zeta(7)}
\\I(7)&=\frac{7}{32}\pi^6\beta(2)-\frac{105}{4}\pi^4\beta(4)+1260\pi^2\beta(6)-10080\beta(8)
\end{align*}

(I'm too lazy to make up an explicit finite-sum nasty-looking formula ;)

Answer (score 2):

Let $c_k=\frac{(-1)^k2\left(2^{2k-1}-1\right)B_{2k}}{(2k)!}$ as seen [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Csc/06/01/02/). $B_y$ denotes the [Bernoulli Numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number)

Then $$|x|<\pi,I(n)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}x^n\left(\frac 1x-\sum _{k=1}^\infty c_kx^{2k-1}\right)dx= \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}x^{n-1}-\sum _{k=1}^\infty c_kx^{2k+n-1}dx= \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n}{n}-\sum _{k=1}^\infty c_k\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2k+n}}{2k+n}$$

Therefore:

$$I(n)= \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n}{n}-\sum _{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k2\left(2^{2k-1}-1\right)B_{2k} \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2k+n}}{(2k+n)(2k)!}=  \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n\left(\frac 1n-2\sum _{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k\left(2^{2k-1}-1\right)B_{2k} \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2k}}{(2k+n)(2k)!}\right) $$
Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: This is an old answer